# Create a string array and display the index and value to console

Tags: c#

This is the code I have so far:

```
string[] animals = { "cow", "pig", "dog", "cat", "mouse", "giraffe", "moose", "deer", "lion", "hippo" };
Console.WriteLine("{0,5}{1,8}", "animal", "index");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Answer (score 5):

```
for(int i = 0; i < animals.length();i++) //Go through the whole array
{
     Console.WriteLine(animals[i] + " " + i); //Output the animal and the index
}
Console.ReadLine();  //Wait for user input.
```

Comment: const int Array_length = 10; //create a named constant
            int[] array = new int[Array_length];//create a new array

            //Calculate value for each array
            for (int counter = 0; counter < array.Length; counter++)
                array[counter] = 2 + 2 * counter;
            Console.WriteLine("{0,5}{1,8}", "Index", "Value");
            Console.ReadLine();
 it doesent work... i tried what you suggested on top for this one one but it doesent seem to be wroking